# NetSuite line item delete inside loop issue

Tags: javascript, netsuite

My Restlet seems to have an issue removing line items inside my loop. If seems there is one record that is always skipped. So if three line items had the id of 111 it only removes two. What issue might be with this code:

```html
var itemcount = update_record.getLineItemCount('item');

for (var j = 1; j <= itemcount; j++)
{
    var lineid = update_record.getLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_line_id', j);

    if (lineid == 111)
    {
        update_record.removeLineItem('item', j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This type of thing will always fail. Run your loop backwards:

```
for(var j = itemCount; i> 0; i--){
```

Otherwise if you delete line 1 then advance your index the next line you are checking (with index 2) was originally line 3 and you've skipped line 2 entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Using the original code, we will mess up the indexing at the line level every time we remove line. So we have to start at the last index (total line count) going to the first index which is 1. See sample code below:

```
var itemcount = update_record.getLineItemCount('item');

for (var j = itemcount; j >0; j--)
{
    var lineid = update_record.getLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_line_id', j);

    if (lineid == 111)
    {
        update_record.removeLineItem('item', j);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for that - helps.

Answer (score 1):

The answers here should use `for (let i = lineCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)` not `for (let i = lineCount; i > 0; i--)`